# Rails field_with_errors and Bootstrap form-horizontal

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my `custom.css.scss` file, I have:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}
```

The problem is that for Bootstrap horizontal forms, the fields will not remain alligned.

The HTML (generated by rails) is:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label class="control-label" for="bookmark_url">Url</label></div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="bookmark_url" name="bookmark[url]" size="30" type="text" value=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/a78B5/2/) to illustrate the problem.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it with the following css:

```
.form-horizontal .field_with_errors
{
  margin: 0;
}

.form-horizontal .field_with_errors:before, .form-horizontal .field_with_errors::after 
{
  display: block;
  clear: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some extraneous `.control-group` divs in there. Simply adding the `error` class to the enclosing `control-group` div should give you the desired result:

```
<div class="control-group error">
  <label class="control-label" for="bookmark_url">Url</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="bookmark_url" name="bookmark[url]" size="30" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the html (generated by rails for the label) is `<div class="field_with_errors"><label ...`, in the jsfiddle I just replaced it with those two extended fields (I updated the question with this html). So this solution doesn't really work here.

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks nothing like that - could you update that too?