# Rails error messages break signup form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top and I have a problem with styles for error messages from rails.

I want to accomplish this:

[image: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/images/figures/blank_signup_password_digest_bootstrap_4_0.png]

But instead of that my form breaks and I get this ugly form:

[image]

I checked a source code and there are nov div tags inserted instead of label and input:

[image]

How to override that behavior and accomplish that form is only highlighted like in the tutorial?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I found out where is the problem. I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.0 and extend is not working there. So, this is not working:

```
#error_explanation {
  color: #f00;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}
```

And because of that this code doesn't work like it should:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I can't find a way to make that extend working. Like control-group is not present...

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, when I add this code to `config/environment.rb` the form doesn't break but can't accomplish red lines around forms where is wrong input:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag.html_safe
```

Comment: If you create your code just like in the tutorial, it should behave just like the tutorial. Did you implement something differently? You haven't shown any of your code.

Comment: @mbratch, I know what is the problem. I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.0 and extend is not working there. I tried a couple of solutions online but no luck. I edited my question with part which is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using Bootstrap 3? The tutorial tells you to use

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
```

in your gemfile. You really should do so, because the tutorial provides you with a whole lot of code that is meant to be used with Bootstrap 2. Of course, it breaks with Bootstrap 3. If you really want to use B3 you will have to change quite a few class names in your views. Among other changes do this:

- change `div class="alert alert-error"` to `div class="alert alert-danger"`
- apply `form-group` and `form-control` classes to your form fields (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20977769/2637573)).
- in your CSS:

  ```
  .field_with_errors {
    @extend .has-error;
  }
  ```
- Then do all the other changes mentioned [here](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#cheat-cheat).

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! I wanted to try Bootstrap 3 and managed to adapt everything except errors. I changed everything as you suggested. My form doesn't break now and everything is highlighted as it should be!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite a common error - have you ever tried either of these:

- [Rails field_with_errors and Bootstrap form-horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511770/rails-field-with-errors-and-bootstrap-form-horizontal)
- [Ruby field_with_errors doesn't @extend .control-group .error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917429/ruby-field-with-errors-doesnt-extend-control-group-error)

[@extend documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend)

---

**Precompile**

Failing that, you may wish to try asset precompiling:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false

$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

---

**Mixins**

This won't fix it directly, but you could create a mixin for the styles, and include that like this:

```
@mixin error {
    display: block;
    etc
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried those links and didn't manage to make it work.